# How to get the memory usage metrices from hadoop ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-dataproc, resourcemanager, namenode

I have a dataproc cluster running in Google cloud with 3 master nodes and 40 worker nodes. I use hadoop ResourceManager to monitor the applications and other metrics like queue usage, memory usage, app running etc. I am unable to get the command to fetch the memory usage for my cluster, where as I use below command to get dfs usage and other metrics.

hdfs admin -report

Please let me know the command to fetch the memory usage on linux server from Resource manager as per below screenshot

[image]

I also gone through the below links for more details but it didnt help me to get what I want

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that information is exposed via JMX at the /jmx url path, as well as the [Metrics API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Metrics_API)

If you want remote JMX access, you can enable that via the yarn-env.sh file

```
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8001"
```

Then point jconsole at port 8001 of the resource manager, and search around for the values you want

Answer (score 0):

If monitoring (dashboarding or alerting) is your end goal, I'd suggest looking into Stackdriver Monitoring. Dataproc is integrated with it and makes a number of cluster metrics available (including Yarn and HDFS).

For a one-off, you can do: `gcloud compute ssh my-cluster-m -c "hdfs admin -report"`

You can also get the same metrics from `clusterMetrics` field by describing your cluster.